# How to find a value in-between n number of tables of a database with same schema?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Some thing like this.

```
select id from all_tables where name = 'sam';
```

Comment: UNION ALL will help.

Comment: _Why_ do you have multiple tables of the same structure to begin with?

Comment: At first this question is not related to php, secondly you didn't specify which database (I guess mysql from the tag) the answer is completely different in each database, third
should ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as it would be the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

If your db is mysql this should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'sam'
```

If you want to limit to a specific database add

```
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db_name';
```